# lapply inside an lapply function

Tags: r

Having just learnt that loops are bad Im now trying to use lapply inside lapply. I have a series of sequentially numbered dataframes. In each one I would like to replace columns 5 and 8 with letters depending on their values so that

```
`if the value is <2 the value is changed to "l" (for loss)`, 
`if it equals 2 the value should be "d"` 
and if >2 it should be "g".
```

My starting dataframe is as follows

```
structure(list(Chromosome = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "2", "20", "21", "22", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "X", "Y"), class = "factor"), Start = c(1L, 100000001L, 
10000001L, 1000001L, 100500001L, 101000001L), Ratio.x = c(1.32971, 
0.990806, 0.991636, 1.01224, 1.00196, 1.00834), MedianRatio.x = c(1.32971, 
1.00378, 0.988738, 0.979015, 1.00378, 1.00378), CopyNumber.x = c(3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Ratio.y = c(-1, 0.718527, 1.09204, -1, 1.07779, 
1.41024), MedianRatio.y = c(-1, 1.07779, 0.814437, 0.814437, 
1.07779, 1.07779), CopyNumber.y = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Chromosome", 
"Start", "Ratio.x", "MedianRatio.x", "CopyNumber.x", "Ratio.y", 
"MedianRatio.y", "CopyNumber.y"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I am using is as follows

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern='total\\d+'))

lapply(lst, function(df) {
  lapply(df, function(x){
  #Mark out diploid as "d"
  x[,5][x[,5] == "2"] <- "d"
  x[,8][x[,8] == "2"] <- "d"
  #Deletions are "l"
  x[,5][x[,5] < 2 & x[,5] !="d"] <- "l"
  x[,8][x[,8] < 2 & x[,8] !="d"] <- "l"
  #Gains are "g"
  x[,5][x[,5] > 2 & x[,5] !="l" & x[,5] !="d"] <- "g"
  x[,8][x[,8] > 2 & x[,8] !="l" & x[,8] !="d"] <- "g"
  #Compare the g's l's and d's
}
)})
```

however I keep getting the error

```
Error in `[.default`(`*tmp*`, , 5) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Whoever taught you that loops are bad, taught you wrong... and they should have taught you that it's more robust to reference columns by name than by number, or that it's very odd to compare an integer with a string (`x[,5]=="2"`).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich R `for` loops bleed scope. That *is* bad.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich. I have amended but the string issue but still have the same problem

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I don't know what you mean by "bleed scope" in this context, but I seriously doubt scoping issues are what the OP (or others) mean when they say "for loops in R are bad".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich `for (i in 1 : 5) { j = i }; i; j` prints values for `i` and `j`. Neither should be defined here (in fact, keeping scope minimal is one of the more fundamental software engineering principles). That’s what I mean. And at least when I say loops are bad in R, that’s what I’m referring to; they’re simply a language feature of R that didn’t receive proper care in its design.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That has nothing to do with _loops_ but a lot with _scope_ which was designed for making programming with data possible interactively and programmatically.  You have your money back guarantee if you're displeased ...

Comment: @Dirk It’s a consequence of the early R development not paying enough heed to software engineering. You can achieve your goal (programming with data) without ignoring best practices. But all that is *irrelevant* because the upshot is nowadays that `for` loops in R do something that is wrong, and using list functions doesn’t have the same problem.

Comment: @Dirk To clarify (I think I misunderstood you before): nothing in the scoping rules of R mandates the behaviour exhibited by the `for` loop, and R’s scoping rules are otherwise properly specified. For instance, `for` could (and should) trivially have been specified as having the same semantics as wrapping it inside a `local` block — in fact, that definition is even possible *inside R*: https://gist.github.com/klmr/e585031913e926352258

Comment: Maybe the OP wanted to say *bad* in a sense of *not efficient*. it might be.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that avoids looping (hidden or otherwise) altogether:

```
df;
##   Chromosome     Start  Ratio.x MedianRatio.x CopyNumber.x   Ratio.y MedianRatio.y CopyNumber.y
## 1          1         1 1.329710      1.329710            3 -1.000000     -1.000000            2
## 2          1 100000001 0.990806      1.003780            2  0.718527      1.077790            2
## 3          1  10000001 0.991636      0.988738            2  1.092040      0.814437            2
## 4          1   1000001 1.012240      0.979015            1 -1.000000      0.814437            2
## 5          1 100500001 1.001960      1.003780            2  1.077790      1.077790            2
## 6          1 101000001 1.008340      1.003780            1  1.410240      1.077790            2
df[,c(5,8)] <- c('l','d','g')[sign(as.matrix(df[,c(5,8)])-2)+2];
df;
##   Chromosome     Start  Ratio.x MedianRatio.x CopyNumber.x   Ratio.y MedianRatio.y CopyNumber.y
## 1          1         1 1.329710      1.329710            g -1.000000     -1.000000            d
## 2          1 100000001 0.990806      1.003780            d  0.718527      1.077790            d
## 3          1  10000001 0.991636      0.988738            d  1.092040      0.814437            d
## 4          1   1000001 1.012240      0.979015            l -1.000000      0.814437            d
## 5          1 100500001 1.001960      1.003780            d  1.077790      1.077790            d
## 6          1 101000001 1.008340      1.003780            l  1.410240      1.077790            d
```

Comment: This is smart — and also completely incomprehensible and debuggable. Please don’t write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `lapply` doesn’t really make sense — you wouldn’t use a loop here either.

Instead, you can replace a column as follows:

```
classify_cnv = function (column)
    ifelse(column < 2, 'l', ifelse(column > 2, 'g', 'd'))
```

… and apply this to the two columns in question:

```
df$CopyNumber.x = classify_cnv(df$CopyNumber.x)
df$CopyNumber.y = classify_cnv(df$CopyNumber.y)
```

You can then put this inside the `lapply` across `data.frame`s:

```
classify_all_cnvs = function (df) {
    df$CopyNumber.x = classify_cnv(df$CopyNumber.x)
    df$CopyNumber.y = classify_cnv(df$CopyNumber.y)
    df
}

result = lapply(lst, classify_all_cnvs)
```

However, it may actually be more appropriate replace the list of `data.frame`s by *one* big `data.frame`, with an extra column specifying which original table the data comes from. How to do this best depends on your exact data structure.